# What does the << C++ operator do, other than shifting?

Tags: c++, operators

I saw a C++ snippet on a Qt sample that contains a few << operators. I'm aware of bit shifting, but it's apparent that these do something else:

In this link: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/itemviews-simpletreemodel-treemodel-cpp.html there's some code that looks as follows:

```
void TreeModel::setupModelData(const QStringList &lines, TreeItem *parent)
{
    QList<TreeItem*> parents;
    QList<int> indentations;
    parents << parent;
    indentations << 0;
    // ...
```

What do the operators do on the last two lines: **parents << parent** and **indentations << 0**

I Googled around but keep landing on pages talking about shift operators.

Does this have something to do with a specialised form of assignment?

Comment: The `<<` is not usually shifting in C++.  It's the formatted insertion operator, with the left hand side an `std::istream`.  In this case, the left hand side is a `QList`, so it could be anything, but if `QList` is well designed, and not into operator overload abuse, it will be something related to formatted insertion.

Comment: @James: Even when used for formatted insertion, the shift operator has some sense of shifting.  And "Shift Operators" is what the Standard calls them.

Comment: @BenVoigt - it is true, yet the majority of cases they are used for something other than shifting.

Comment: @BenVoigt The abstraction in iostream is *not* shifting, but formatting/parsing.  Unformatted reads and writes don't use them.  And this is the usual use in C++, and certainly the first use a beginning C++ programmer will see.

Comment: @James: Whether it is "usual" depends completely on the kind of code. The majority of the systems that run C++ code don't have a console or filesystem and don't use iostreams for the I/O interfaces they do have (e.g. serial ports), but do use bit operations for controlling I/O pins.

Comment: @BenVoigt I would have thought that most of those were written in C:-).

Comment: @James: Many C++ language features are very useful in embedded systems even where most of the Standard library is inapplicable.  You certainly want to catch as many errors as possible at compile time, which means even C code should be run through a C++ compiler for the superior type safety.  But templates, overloaded functions, `constexpr`, inline functions, encapsulation, RAII synchronization objects are useful in even the smallest systems.  For slightly larger systems, type safe allocation and virtual dispatch are useful also.

Comment: @BenVoigt I'm not saying that they shouldn't be written in C++; I'd certainly use C++ if I had the choice, for the reasons you give.  But from what I've seen, they aren't.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The easiest way to find the answer is to look at what types the operator is being applied to. The left operand is a `QList<TreeItem*>` and the right operand is a `TreeItem*`. This should give you the hint to look up [the documentation for `QList`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlist.html).

In the documentation you'll find [the specification for `operator<<`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlist.html#operator-lt-lt-2):

> ```
> QList<T> & QList::operator<< ( const T & value )
> ```
>
> This is an overloaded function.
>
> Appends value to the list.

So, where `T` is the type of the elements in your `QList`, which is `TreeItem*`, this overload of `operator<<` takes a reference to a `T` and adds it to the list.

This is supposed to be consistent with the metaphor used for inserting into the output stream, such as with `std::cout << "Hello!";`. That is, it's often considered to be an *insertion operator*. On the other hand, `operator>>` is often used for *extraction*. However, it's really just being used here for syntactic sugar.

Comment: This is clearly abuse of operator overloading.  In C++, the abstraction of `<<` is formatted insertion.  Unless some sort of conversion to an external format is involved, using `<<` is abusive.

Comment: @JamesKanze Actually, I agree. I think people way overuse overloading of `operator<<`. I'll make it "This is supposed to be consistent...".

Comment: It's unfortunate that different containers use `<<` in such different ways.  `std::valarray` uses it to mean element-wise application of the shift operator.  OTOH, I think `QList`'s use probably pre-existed `valarray`.

Comment: The abuse of `operator<<()` overloading started with it's use in iostreams. And if you count the times when `operator<<()` overloads are used other than for iostreams, I'll bet that it's used for plain insertion more often than formatted insertion. The flood gates were opened, and I think there's no going back.

Comment: @MichaelBurr It's almost like there could have been a separate operator for shifting and for insertion. The insertion operator would just not be used unless it was overloaded. But then, we might as well just make custom operators possible. That would only lead to more abuse.

Comment: Awesome, that clarifies it. I'll keep my eye on the documentation for operator overloads next time. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Some of what makes C++ polymorphism more powerful, and sometimes argued misused, is operator overloading which allows you to provide a custom implementation to some of the common operators included in the language such as `+, -, <<,` and more.

Examples of this would be:

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &out, RationalNumber &fraction)
{
    return out << fraction.getNumerator() << "/" << fraction.getDenominator();
}


bool RationalNumber::operator == ( const RationalNumber & right )
{
    return (this->Numerator == right.Numerator && this->Denominator == right.Denominator ? true:false);
}
```

As you can probably see, this gives me the power to do what ever I want inside the operator including things unrelated to the initial meaning of it. This is, from what I've read, the reason why such a tool is not included in Java.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, you can overload operator. So << operator depends on whatever else you define on the operator overload. Its also the same for other operator like >>, +, -, etc

Answer (score 1):

<< is overridden in QList

From the QT reference manual:

```
**QList<T> & QList::operator<< ( const QList<T> & other )**
Appends the items of the other list to this list and returns a reference to this list.

See also operator+=() and append().

**QList<T> & QList::operator<< ( const T & value )**
This is an overloaded function.

Appends value to the list.
```